# Mages game engine with tomcat or use Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I have looked around and cannot find any documentation or tutorials on how to run the Mages game engine in android:

http://code.google.com/p/mages/downloads/list

From the list above could someone please explain what I need to download. I need to make a simple game between 2 emulators. I noticed that the installation files in the link above has a clien.apk and a GASP file which is for Tomcat. I already have tomcat installed so this would be ideal.

Please help I am really stuck on how and which one to use.

Edit: Would it be easier just to use engine for this, is it possible to create a game between 2 players using andengine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a link which shows how to setup AndEngine so I'll just try and use that for now. 
Thanks for all the answers they really helped.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-genimutmQ&feature=player_embedded